# The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, exception

```
try
{
    String endPointAddr = "net.tcp://localhost:8000/MyService";
    NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
    tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
    tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
    tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
    tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endPointAddr);

    Console.WriteLine("::::: WCF Service Demo :::::");
    Console.WriteLine("Attempt to connect to: " + endPointAddr);


    ChannelFactory<IServices> WCF = new ChannelFactory<IServices>(tcpBinding, endpointAddress);
    IServices proxy = WCF.CreateChannel();

    using (WCF as IDisposable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to: " + endPointAddr);
        Dictionary<long, DATALINK> dicDataLink = proxy.getDataLink();
        lblCTRGData.Text = dicTRGDataLink.Count.ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblCTRGData.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

this code run fluently if dictionary has 50 to 100 records but records is greater than that error has been occurred The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Comment: And your question is?  Are you by any chance coding a service call with the proxy in a using statement, and the service has thrown an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the stack trace or the code that is failing but it sounds like your wcf client has failed for some reason which has put it into a faulted state and you are trying to use it again. Or that you are using a using statement with your proxy.

[Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx)

Comment: This blog post mentions the link you provide but also gives an alternate solution by putting a wrapper around the WCF client proxy class and providing a Dispose method that implements the code from the MSDN article.  Allows for the continued use of the using statement and centralizes the fix if you have to call your WCF client in multiple places.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/03/18/avoiding-problems-with-the-using-statement-and-wcf-service-proxies.aspx